# Подсветка первых 5 мест в таблице

Tags: php, css

Есть турнирная таблица(php выводит из mysql), из которой первые 5 команд выходят в play-off
нужно сделать , чтобы первые 5 команд подcвечивались цветом(любым)

```
echo '<table class="tournament" border="3"  >';
    echo '<tr>';
echo '<th></th>';
    echo '<th class="main_name" >Team name</th>';
   echo  '<th>Matches Played</th>';
    echo '<th>Matches Won</th>';
    echo '<th>Matches Won OT</th>';
    echo '<th>Matches Lost OT</th>';
    echo '<th>Matches Lost</th>';
    echo '<th>Goals Scored</th>';
    echo '<th>Goals Missed</th>';
     echo '<th class="team_points" >Team Points</th>';

  echo '</tr>'; 
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { 
    // Display the score data



    echo '<tr>'; 
    if (is_file(GW_UPLOADPATH . $row['team_logo']) && filesize(GW_UPLOADPATH . $row['team_logo']) > 0) {
      echo '<td><img class="playerphoto" src="' . GW_UPLOADPATH . $row['team_logo'] . '" alt="Photo" /></td>';
    }
    else {
      echo '<td><img src="' . GW_UPLOADPATH . '' . '" alt="" /></td>';
    }

    echo '<td  class="team_name" >' . $row['team_name'] . '</td>';
      echo '<td> ' . $row['matches_played'] . '</td>';
        echo ' <td>' . $row['matches_won'] . '</td>';
              echo ' <td>' . $row['matches_won_ot'] . '</td>';
                echo ' <td>' . $row['matches_lost_ot'] . '</td>';
                  echo ' <td>' . $row['matches_lost'] . '</td>';
                    echo ' <td>' . $row['goals_scored'] . '</td>';
                      echo ' <td>' . $row['goals_missed'] . '</td>';
                       echo ' <td>' . $row['team_points'] . '</td>';


  }
 echo ' </tr>';
  echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Просто добавьте счётчик и первым пяти элементам присвойте css класс.

Comment: @user287120, зачем усложнять, если можно [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Comment: @user287120 не подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: Перед циклом while объявляешь переменную и в кожной итерации автоинкрементируешь ее, но перед этим проверяешь, если она меньше или ровна 5, то дописываешь css класс к выводимому html коду.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучше это сделать без присвоении лишних классов

```css
table.tournament tr:nth-child(-n+5){
 background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table class="tournament">
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Для подсветки строк все зависимости от сортировки, нужно добавить класс строки таблицы:

```
echo '<table class="tournament" border="3"  >';
echo '<thead>'
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th></th>';
echo '<th class="main_name" >Team name</th>';
echo '<th>Matches Played</th>';
echo '<th>Matches Won</th>';
echo '<th>Matches Won OT</th>';
echo '<th>Matches Lost OT</th>';
echo '<th>Matches Lost</th>';
echo '<th>Goals Scored</th>';
echo '<th>Goals Missed</th>';
echo '<th class="team_points" >Team Points</th>';

echo '</tr>'; 

echo '</thead>';
echo '<tbody>';

$i = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { 
    // Display the score data
    if($i<=5){
        echo '<tr class="marked">';
    }else{
        echo '<tr>';
    }
    $i++;
    if (is_file(GW_UPLOADPATH . $row['team_logo']) && filesize(GW_UPLOADPATH . $row['team_logo']) > 0) {
        echo '<td><img class="playerphoto" src="' . GW_UPLOADPATH . $row['team_logo'] . '" alt="Photo" /></td>';
    }else{
        echo '<td><img src="' . GW_UPLOADPATH . '' . '" alt="" /></td>';
    }
    echo '<td  class="team_name" >' . $row['team_name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td> ' . $row['matches_played'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['matches_won'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['matches_won_ot'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['matches_lost_ot'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['matches_lost'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['goals_scored'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['goals_missed'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['team_points'] . '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
```

В css уже прописывать стиль:

```
table.tournament tr.marked{
    // стиль
}
```

Comment: да , спасибо за помощь, я так делал, но когда сортирую (по кол-ву забитых шайб , некорректные команды подсвечиваются) надо чтоб 5-рка лидеров по очкам в независимости от сортировка светилась

Comment: Обновил ответ. Внес правки в Ваш код

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: Если ответ решил вопрос, отметьте его